# onepage checkout not moving to next step after billing info

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout

I'm new user of magento, & my domain Is www.zinzzy.com where having problem in onepage checkout page, Next step not moving after billing information , i have checked firebug i think it takes ajax uploader image/file path from base \app\design\frontend\base\default, while it takes my theme file \app\design\frontend{theme name}\default.Please help me any one.

Thanx in advance

Comment: Works for me as guest.

Answer (score 0):

you have the following error please check

```
Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in /home/zinzzy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php on line 134
```

Comment: Thanx for response,

Comment: As i've said,I'm new user of magento, So please if its possible to explain in details this error, that i can resolved it

Comment: missing or corrupt file maybe during ftp transfer?

Answer (score 0):

As per Pradeep Sanku's answer

```
Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in /home/zinzzy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php on line 134
```

it means soap extension in not installed on your server.check phpinfo() to confirm and install extension on server.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't php-soap installed on your server, or this extension is disabled from php.ini. Install and enable php-soap and try again.